# mediastreamvalidator validate Warning

Tags: macos, xcode4, http-live-streaming, mediastreamsegmenter

I am trying to use HTTP Live Streaming in my App. For that i am segmenting my stream using this command.

```
sudo /usr/bin/mediafilesegmenter -I -f Desktop/MySegment -a -t 10.00 Desktop/MyVideo.mp4
```

I validate the stream by this command

```
mediastreamvalidator validate http://www.xyz.com/prog_index.m3u8
```

But i getting some warnings (illustrated below) while validating it.

```
Playlist Validation: 

    OK

Segments:

fileSequence26.aac:

WARNING: Media segment exceeds target duration of 9.98 seconds by 1.32 seconds (segment duration is 11.31 seconds)

fileSequence28.aac:

WARNING: Media segment exceeds target duration of 10.01 seconds by 1.56 seconds (segment duration is 11.56 seconds)

fileSequence29.aac:

WARNING: Media segment exceeds target duration of 9.98 seconds by 1.39 seconds (segment duration is 11.38 seconds)

fileSequence42.aac:

WARNING: Media segment exceeds target duration of 10.01 seconds by 1.23 seconds (segment duration is 11.24 seconds)
```

What should i do for remove this warnings?
Anyone can help in this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should increase the duration to be longer than all of the segments. You can do this by modifying the `#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:` My guess is that your playlist has a target duration of 10, but some of your segments are longer than 11 seconds.

To be fully compliant with the HLS draft spec, your target duration should be changed to 12 seconds. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-pantos-http-live-streaming-10#section-3.4.2